# simple_format and 2+ newline(\n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails and need to show text, having 3 or more newline characters in a row.

I found `simple_format` method, but it works with 2,3,4,... symbols identically

> Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in < p > tags.

For example, my text is

```
1.9.3p0 :015 > Article.last.text
=> "1\n\n2\n\n\n\n33"
```

when i do `<%= simple_format Article.last.text.html_safe %>` it generates me this view:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
# but i need <br/> or smth else there
<p>3</p>
```

Other solutions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: if you want to preserve all the newlines why not just do `Article.last.text.gsub("\n", '<br>')`. You still have to check or make the text to be html safe before marking it to be html safe though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I might still be missing something, but why not just use `string.gsub(a, b)`:

```
"1\n\n2\n\n\n\n33".gsub("\n", "<br />").html_safe # => "1<br/><br/>2<br/><br/><br/><br/>33"
```

Surely you can also pass the previous line to `simple_format` to have the line wrapped into a `<p>` tag.